# Possibilities in German to minimize a term?

Tags: morphology, neologism, suffix, diminutive

I stumbled upon the English term [*Truthiness*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truthiness)

> "truth" that a person claims to know intuitively "from the gut" in that it "feels right" without regard to evidence, logic, intellectual examination, or facts

I like this word very much, especially in the context of conspiracy theories.

But it seems impossible to translate as a single German word, despite German having common diminutive suffixes like *-chen*.

What are *general* common rules and colloquial options to minimize (*verniedlichen*) German terms by using suffixes and/or phonetic tricks?

Comment: I don't think the term is what you're searching for, but maybe it evolved in a similar way - I just stumbled upon it from the other side - what does "Wahrscheinlichkeit" mean? Something seems true - 'scheint wahr'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Truthiness* isn't a minimization of the word *truth*, though — what Colbert did when he invented that phrase was incorrectly turn the word *truth* into the adjective *truthy* by adding *-y* to it (correct adjective would be "true", of course), and then turn it back into a noun by adding *-ness*.

If you wanted to do a similar thing to the word *Wahrheit*, you'd end up with *Wahrheitlichkeit* or *Wahrheitigkeit*, or, if you want fewer syllables, you can start out with *wahr* and get *Wahrlichkeit* or *Wahrigkeit*.

Out of those options, I like "Wahrheitlichkeit" best, but none of them are quite as funny or pithy as "truthiness".

In general, you can minimize German terms by adding the suffixes *-chen* (*Schirmchen*, *Kätzchen*) or *-lein* (*Häuslein*, *Tischlein*). The vowel often becomes an umlaut when you do this.

German dialects also have minimizing suffixes of their own, e.g. *-le* in Swabian or *-erl* in Bavarian.

Comment: +1 for the etymological explanation. truthiness is just a example for possible *Verniedlichung*, the question is more how to build such *verniedlichende Begriffe* in general in German. *Wahrheit* isnt probably the best term to show this.

Comment: I edited my answer to be a bit more general. Someone else should probably add some more detail on how to know whether it's "-chen" or "-lein", or when to use an umlaut, because I actually don't know what the rules are there.

Answer (score 6):

It should be pointed out, that "truthiness" is a coined word (by Stephen Colbert in this case, with the intention to make a joke). So basically, you could equally make up a German word:

> Wahrheitchen,
>
> Wahrheitlein,
>
> Wahrheitle (schwäbisch),
>
> Wahrheiterl (bayrisch),
>
> Wirklichkeitchen,
>
> Wirklichkeitigkeit (intentionally violating usual rules of constructing a word),
>
> Wahrhaftigkeitchen,
>
> Wahrhäftchen,
>
> ...

None of these words exist in the dictionary (yet), and admittedly, none of them sound as good or as funny as Truthiness.

Comment: +1 imo *Wahrheiterl* is just perfect lol. If possible try to generalize this a bit more, truthiness was just a single motivating example. Probably the solution to this problem lies proper use of dialects, they seem to offer more phonetic options than high german, the high german options sound pretty artificial